# Why does adding [0] after the delete count in splice() return just a number?

Tags: javascript, array-splice

First of all sorry for the long title, I really didn't know how to word it better.

In the middle of solving _.shuffle in underscore, I encountered the use of splice. Here is my original code :

```
shuffle = function(array) {
  var shuffledArray = [];
  var total = array.length;
  var copiedArray = array.slice();
  while (total){
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);
    shuffledArray.push(copiedArray.splice(randomNum,1));
    total--;
  }
  return shuffledArray;
};
var originArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(shuffle(originArray));
```

However after testing just I realized it will return each value inside a [ ], instead of just the value.

i.e.

```
[ [ 4 ], [ 3 ], [ 1 ], [ 2 ] ]
//instead of [ 4, 3, 1, 2]
```

When I changed this line (added '[0]' after the deleteCount in splice)

```
shuffledArray.push(copiedArray.splice(randomNum,1));
```

into this

```
//edited
shuffledArray.push(copiedArray.splice(randomNum,1)[0]);
```

the return array that I get is what I wanted, which is

```
[ 3, 1, 2, 4 ] //values are not in [ ]
```

Can someone explain how adding [0] after splice() makes the value not return in [ ] or why not having [0] does?

Comment: `1[0]` return _undefined_ so you call same as `copiedArray.splice(randomNum)`

Comment: i not quite understand what you try to do?

Comment: @Grundy: `1[0]` is indeed `undefined`, but `copiedArray.splice(randomNum)` and `copiedArray.splice(randomNum, undefined)` are **not** the same thing.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand why writing 1[0] will return the value as is and not inside  [ ]

Comment: Are you sure you're not using `copiedArray.splice(randomNum,1)[0]`?

Comment: @Tinah: As far as I can tell, `copiedArray.splice(randomNum, undefined)` returns a blank array. Your question is unclear about what you're trying to do, why you would ever think of doing `1[0]`, your ultimate goal...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yep, you right :-) with _undefined_ returned empty array

Comment: @Luaan: You mean, like, [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.splice)? Note the opening words relate to the number of arguments, not what their values are. Or you can open a console in a browser and try it.

Comment: @Tinah, i think you want `[0]` after `splice` like `array.splice(0, 1)[0]`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Browser are known to differ in details like this, but yeah, the spec link is exactly what I wanted :) And just to note, when I try Tinah's code in Chrome, it works *exactly* as with `undefined` (because, well, `1[0]` *is* `undefined`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder @ralh yes you're right, I was using `copiedArray.splice(randomNum,1)[0]` not, `copiedArray.splice(randomNum,1[0])` smh

Comment: so does adding [0] just mean the element I removed is now being added to the zero index of the new array?

Comment: @Tinah, are you sure that you need `splice`? do you see [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)?

Comment: No :) You're simply taking the first element of the (single element) array returned by `splice`, and pushing that.

Comment: @Luaan yea, now I see it. I am just pushing the zero index of the array that splice() extracted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`splice` returns an array. When you push an array into an array, you get an array of arrays. By adding the `[0]`, you push the first element of the array instead. This is no Javascript weirdness - it's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @Tinah It's a very weird misunderstanding, I must say. Frighteningly, I can imagine this working the way you (wrongly) expect in some unsafe language like C under some specific conditions - and failing miserably in real world use once in a while.

Comment: I think I was more confused when I thought my code was `copiedArray.splice(randomNum,1[0]` now that I realized that mistake. It makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected and was confirmed in the comments, you were using `copiedArray.splice(randomNum,1)[0]`, not `copiedArray.splice(randomNum,1[0])`.

EDIT: That was the original question, and it was since edited.

And since `splice` returns an array (in your case, an array with one number), taking the first element of the array achieves exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Splice returns an array of the deleted elements. By adding `[0]` you are effectively selecting the first item in the returned array.

Answer (score -2):

Try not to reinvent the wheel !
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.shuffle.php

If you really want to, try this in your while:

```
  while (total){
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * total);
    ShuffledArray[] = array[randomNum]; //add an item to next pos
    unset(array[randomNum]); //remove the item added
    array = array_values(array); //reindex array
    total--;
  }
```

Best of luck !